# How do I get LaTeX to output to the right-hand page only?

Tags: header-footer, memoir, double-sided

I am doing a book of poetry for a friend, using Memoir and the poetry package.  She would like the poems to print only on the right-hand pages.  I can get poems to begin only on right-hand pages, but any poem that goes onto a second page obviously spills onto a left-hand page.  How do I change this?

Comment: Use `oneside` option. By the way which document class you are using?

Comment: And the left-hand pages (the ones that will not contain text) must be numbered or not?

Comment: Gonzalo - The left-hand pages should be unnumbered.

Comment: Harish - I am using memoir.

Comment: You can use `\cleardoublepage` to begin another poem. But you have to redefine the page style to clean the page numbers.

Comment: Sigur - My problem isn't with new poems.  It is with poems that extend onto multiple pages.

Comment: So, in fact, what you need is to change the page numbers only for odd numbers. Then, just print in oneside. For example, one pdf file with 5 pages, but numbered as 1,3,5,7,9. Then, you print in normal way and you will have the poems only on right hand pages. Is this what you want?

Comment: Sigur, yes, but openside makes the whole file print in this way.  I would like to have some elements (copyright page, introduction, etcetera) print as normal, but to have large sections print only oneside.  My problem is that oneside is too general.  I want to be able to toggle between oneside and twoside within the document, or to be able to force twosided printing to leave the left-hand side blank at given points.

Comment: I suggest you to produce various pdf files and then you can join them easily (using `pdftk` in linux, for example).

Comment: How big can your poem grow? Will it go beyond 2 pages?

Comment: Harish - Yes, some of the poems get quite long.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This solution is also based on package `atbegshi`. If an "even" poem page would be
printed, then an empty page is output before. The tricky part is fixing the
page counters on the page and in the `.log` file.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{zref-abspage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newif\ifoddpoem
\newif\ifoddpoemPageInc
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \ifoddpoem
    \ifodd\value{abspage}%
      \stepcounter{page}%
      \global\oddpoemPageInctrue
      \advance\value{page} by -1\relax
    \else
      \stepcounter{abspage}%
      \global\oddpoemPageIncfalse
      \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
      \AtBeginShipoutOriginalShipout\null
      \stepcounter{page}%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\newenvironment{oddpoem}{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \oddpoemtrue
}{%
  \clearpage
  \ifoddpoemPageInc
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \global\oddpoemPageIncfalse
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\section{Text before poem}
\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{oddpoem}
  \section{Short poem}
  \lipsum[5-8]
\end{oddpoem} 

\section{Text after short poem}
\lipsum[9-12]

\begin{oddpoem}
  \section{Long poem}
  \lipsum[13-18]
  \lipsum[22-24]
\end{oddpoem}   

\section{Text after long poem}
\lipsum[25-29]

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Heiko - This works really well.  There is some conflict with the poetry package that I'm using, but nothing that I can't fix.  Thanks.